# Assigning new role to already existing user in RDS

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, roles

We have a RDS instance, type:  'db.r5.xlarge' hosted for Aurora PostgreSQL.

A default user 'rdsadmin' was automatically created with 'SUPERUSER' role assigned when we spin up the RDS instance for the first time.

When spinning the instance we created master user 'X'. The 'X' does not have SUPERUSER permissions.

We want to assign 'pg_read_server_files' role to user 'X', but in this case we do not have login credentials to 'rdsadmin' user as it was a default root user provided by AWS when the RDS instance was created.

Are there any workarounds in this case to assign a new role to an existing user?

We have tried "GRANT pg_read_server_files to X;"
But, we receive an error:
"ERROR: Cannot issue GRANT on the "pg_read_server_files" role.
Detail: Cannot GRANT on the "pg_read_server_files" role without being a member of the role."

Comment: @gshpychka
The user is created at the time when we spin up the instance, and it is called master user.

Comment: When you create an RDS instance you have to specify a username and password for your master database user account. If you "do not have the login credentials" to that account, then you lost them, and you will need to follow these steps to reset the master user password: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/reset-master-user-password-rds

Comment: When you create an RDS instance you cannot access the superuser role, as it's a managed service. This is to prevent exactly what it seems you want to be able to do, have access to the server-side files, also backups, upgrades, etc. There are some problems with this approach, as the superuser role isn't fine-grained enough in some ways. So you will typically find that you will need to dip into the not-quite-superuser (you call this "X") to handle some admin tasks and for stuff like taking ownership of objects. If you really need superuser access then don't use a managed service